# adding a subview layer on UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, layer

I have a full-screen UIWebView, and I want to add a semi-transparent subview on top of it. As I do so, I cant click on any of the links on the UIWebview, which tells me that the events are captured by the topmost layer of the view hierarchy, which is the semi-transparent subview. [myUIWebView becomeFirstResponder] doesnt seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIView` has `allowUserInteraction` enabled by default
If the subview was for example a `UIImageView` you should be able to catch input because `allowUserInteraction` is off.

So give `allowUserInteraction` a try.  If you want input on both then you will need to catch it in the subview and send unused input down.